# Guidance on refactoring complex dagger implementation

Tags: android, dependency-injection, robolectric, dagger

Our large android application makes extensive use of dagger - it simplifies the codebase and assists with unit testing using Robolectric.  Generally, we are very pleased with the way it works.

Over time, numerous dagger modules have been developed providing object injections for various aspects of the application.  The approach feels fragmented with unclear demarcation between modules.  Inevitably, the same object has wound up in multiple modules and multiple modules are required to satisfy the @Injects annotations in some classes.  The combination of library=true and complete=false means that we are missing out on some compile time checking as well.  Adding new objects to a module can be tricky and sometimes it feels as if we are fighting dagger rather than using it.

We also have a set of test modules that provide mock objects but they duplicate many of the issues in the main app.

The time has come to refactor our dagger implementation and clean up some of the organic growth that is now beginning to hurt us.  Is there a preferred approach to implementing dagger?

- Should we place everything in one large module - one for the main app and one for the unit test?
- Should we split the existing modules down into lots of tiny modules that are very specifically focused on a function and include those modules to roll them up into a feature level module?

Any guidance based on experience would be most welcome.